# How to change locale for DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android, dialog, locale, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I've read many links about this question and I know that this class is using default locale
but I need to use Armenian locale which isn't in the standart locale of devices. How can I fixed that?

Comment: "but I need to use Armenian locale" - by this I assume you mean that your device does **not** have Armenian language support at all - and you wish to support Armenian for this particular dialog?

Comment: @Jens I got 4.0 and it does have Armenian leanguage support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember well DatePickerDialog is localized by default. So if you put your app on a device who is on Armenian locale, it will adapt it automatically.